# Size of plot in R-Markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

How I can reduce the size of a plot in a R-Markdown chunk? I want to render a .pdf but the plot is too large.

```
ggplot(data = test_datac,repr.plot.width = 7, repr.plot.height = 4) + 
  geom_line(size=0.5,mapping = aes(x = Period, y = gdpg))
```

I have tried to add `repr.plot.width = 7`, `repr.plot.height = 4` but this didn't reduce the size.

Comment: Set it in your chunk options, e.g. `{r, fig.height = 6, fig.width = 12}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the pot size in an R-Markdown code chunk by setting the `fig.height=` and `fig.width=` chunk arguments:

````
```{r fig.height=8, fig.width=8}
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width), size = 0.5)
```
````